# How to use CAST to replace ::date in postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to to **replace ::date** and **use CAST** for below SQL code ?

```
SELECT to_char(d,   'DD Mon YYYY" to "') || to_char(d+6, 'DD Mon YYYY') AS week 
FROM  (
  SELECT generate_series(d1,d1 + interval '4 weeks',interval '1 week')::date AS d
  FROM  (SELECT date_trunc('week', to_date('January2014', 'MonthYYYY')) AS d1) sub1
  ) sub2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting a value to a `date` can be done in either of the following ways:

- `value::date`
- `CAST(value as date)`

If you would like to create your own conversion function you can use the `CREATE CAST`
command.

[CREATE CAST documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createcast.html)

Comment: (CAST(d1,d1 + interval '4 weeks',interval '1 week' AS DATE)) gives error like ERROR: syntax error at or near "," in d1,d

Comment: That is because you did not put the cast around a value, but around 3 values: `d1`, `d1 + interval '4 weeks'`, and `interval '1 week'`.

Comment: Thanks Dwayne , could you please show how this cane be done ?

Comment: Try a simpler query and work up to the one you want. Do you know what `generate_series(...)` does?

Comment: got it working as below 
(CAST (generate_series(d1,d1 + interval '4 weeks',interval '1 week') AS DATE ))

Answer (score 1):

Try below commend:

**cast(d as date) instead of ::date**

For More Reference:http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/Pine.LNX.3.96.980617121743.1509D-100000@proxy.bazzanese.com

Comment: (CAST(d1,d1 + interval '4 weeks',interval '1 week' AS DATE)) gives error like ERROR: syntax error at or near "," in d1,d